# Race condition in FastApi?

Tags: rest, concurrency, fastapi, race-condition

I have this endpoint in FastApi that uses the all_rooms variable. So I thought that there is a possibility to have a race condition if there is multiples requests to this endpoint because of the array all_rooms. can be? Since FastApi is concurrent (mixed with parallelism).

```
all_rooms: List[Chat] = []
#Add an instance of a socket manager class to the array of rooms
@app.post("/open")
async def open_websocket():
    new_chat = Chat()
    all_rooms.append(new_chat)
    room_id = len(all_rooms) - 1
    # If admin is not online do not notify
    admin.add_room(room_id) 

    return {'room_id': room_id}
```

Comment: If you're only using a single worker and you're running your endpoints as async - and never calling await, only a single execution will be present at the same time. However, it's usually better to design for something to be called parallel-ish, and assume that a race will happen, instead of trying to assume that it doesn't - and in that case, at least use exclusive locking of the resource.